# standardize number of character in a numerical string of a data.frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame

```
     a c
1   98 1
2   99 2
3  100 3
4  101 4
5  102 5
6  103 6
7  999 7
8 1003 8
```

and i would like to transform column a to column b as below

```
     a c    b
1   98 1 0098
2   99 2 0099
3  100 3 0100
4  101 4 0101
5  102 5 0102
6  103 6 0103
7  999 7 0999
8 1003 8 1003
```

The code i employed at the moment is

```
a <- c(98:103,999,1003)
c <- 1:8
b <- a

data <- data.frame(a,c,b)
for (i in 1:dim(data)[1]){
    if (data[i,1]/100 <1) {
        data[i,3] <- paste("00",data[i,1],sep="")
    } else if (data[i,1]/1000 < 1){
        data[i,3] <- paste(0,data[i,1],sep="")
    } else{
        data[i,3] <- data[i,1]
    }
}
```

But i found this code perform very slow as my real data with over 60,000 instances.

How can i optimize the code to achieve the task?

Comment: One line using sprintf().

Comment: thanks introduce me this amazing in-built function @joran

data$a <- sprintf("%04.0f",data$a)

Comment: Even simpler: `sprintf("%04d",data$a)`

Comment: @Yin, you can post an answer yourself and accept it to show that this problem has been solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the assist from @joran and @thelatemail.
I solved the problem with following code:

```
    a <- c(98:103,999,1003)
    c <- 1:8
    data <- data.frame(a,c)
    data$b <- sprintf("%04d",data$a)
```